# The word "detector" is not recognized as a token in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I defined a grammar rule

```
variable : ID ;
```

where ID is defined in the lexer grammar as

```
ID : VALID_ID_START VALID_ID_CHAR* ;
fragment VALID_ID_START : ('a' .. 'z') | ('A' .. 'Z') | '_' ;
fragment VALID_ID_CHAR : VALID_ID_START | ('0' .. '9') ;
```

However in my test, the literal word "detector" is not recognized as a token of variable. It works as expected as soon as I remove any character from the word. Is "detector" a reserved word in ANTLR4? If yes, how can I get around that since this word is a common variable in my work.

Comment: Which input string did you use to test this grammar?

Comment: Just the word "detector" without the quote.

Comment: If it's not recognized as an ID token, what is it recognized as?

Comment: It couldn't recognize that as anything, but just reported an error: ChdHotspotQueryLanguage::variable:1:0: mismatched input 'detector' expecting ID

Comment: I tested with many other words and some random string of characters which just worked fine.

Comment: If it didn't recognize it as anything, it'd give you a "token recognition error". "mismatched input" means that it recognized it as something other than ID.

Comment: Try running `grun` with the `-tokens` option to see what your input is recognized as or just go through all your lexer rules and check whether any of them could match "detector" other than `ID`.

Comment: I did the test using ANTLR4's plugin for Eclipse. That was the only error message I got. In the Parse Tree view, the word "detector" was shown as "<detector>" in red, rather than "detector" in black as recognized token, coming down from the token "variable". I guess I should write my own test code and see what happens after entering the token "variable".

Comment: I don't doubt that that's the error message you got. I'm telling you what that error message means: that "detector" was recognized as something other than `ID`. You'll have to find out as what kind of token "detector" was recognized instead.

Comment: Thanks @sepp2k, I will try what you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem. Somewhere in my lexer rules, the word "detector" is used to define a different token. Thanks to @sepp2k for his comments that guided me to right direction of solving the problem.